# CSS - Flex property to align div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm creating tow divs inside another outer div. What I want is I need to align these two divs at the two ends of the outer div. I have attached my code above, but it doesn't work. So can you please help ?

```css
.outer {
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="outer-grid">one</div>
  <div class="outer-grid">two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean *it doesn't work*? Please provide the expected result, and the result you currently have.

Comment: Also, please include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a snippet.

Comment: I have edited my code. can you please check?

Comment: Yes, the code works. But isn't it already giving the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your other details are.  If this outer div is your container, just these two might provide space between for the items.

```
#box-container {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```